# How to send arraylist data to a column in mysql table..?

Tags: java, php, android

Im am currently working on  a android project which has a calenderpicker(Timesquare calenderpicker) and the selected dates from calenderpicker is stored in a arrayList. My problem is i want to send this dates from Arraylist and put it in the sql table using Php.

Im a beginner in both android and php

This is the calenderpicker Code.!!

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayList<Date> selectedDates = (ArrayList<Date>) calendarPickerView
                        .getSelectedDates();
                Log.d("newFormatDate", sdf.format(selectedDates.get(0)));
                Log.d("newFormatDate", sdf.format(selectedDates.get(selectedDates.size() - 1)));
//                Toast.makeText(Selectdate.this, selectedDates.toString(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int nowadays = selectedDates.size();
```

Comment: Note that for SQL data, it'd be more standard to store a list of values as multiple rows/entries in your table, rather than storing a list in a single field.

Comment: You'll be able to do that using TypeConverters.

Answer (score 0):

define dataset class object that will act as dataset constructor first. It should have the same or similar structure to the table on mysql on the the server.

The dataset class object constructor may look like this:

```
public class Profile {
    private Integer id;
    private String id_card;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public Profile() {
        super();
    }

    public Profile(Integer id, String id_card, String name, String phone,
                   String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.id_card = id_card;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIdCard() {
        return id_card;
    }

    public void setIdCard(String id_card) {
        this.id_card = id_card;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Then, You can use that class. And fill the class object records. Notice, It may was formed as json string from local dataset or just an array list variable.

If it formed as json string. You can fill the list like this.

```
private List<Profile> processResponse(String response){
    List<Profile> myProfile = new ArrayList<Profile>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("params_name1");
        
        Profile myProfile = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            
            myProfile = new Profile();
            myProfile.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            myProfile.setIdCard(obj.getString("id_card"));
            myProfile.setName(obj.getString("full_name"));
            myProfile.setPhone( obj.getString("phone_num") );
            myProfile.setAddress(obj.getString("adress1"));
            
            list.add(myProfile);
            
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        
    }
    return list;
}
```

If it just simple array list, You can do it through **for each** loop

```
ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( "alex", "brian", "charles") );

List<Profile> list = new ArrayList<Profile>();
Profile myProfile = null;
int iNum = 0;
for(String name : namesList)
{
    iNum++;
    myProfile = new Profile();
    myProfile.setId(iNum);
    myProfile.setName(name);
    list.add(myProfile);
}
```

And then You can looping the class object records who was filled with local data to update data on the server. You can use async task to do that.

So the full code before async task could be like this

```
public class Profile {
    private Integer id;
    private String id_card;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public Profile() {
        super();
    }

    public Profile(Integer id, String id_card, String name, String phone,
                   String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.id_card = id_card;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIdCard() {
        return id_card;
    }

    public void setIdCard(String id_card) {
        this.id_card = id_card;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}


public class ListAdapterProfile extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private Context context;
    private List<Profile> list, filterd;

    public ListAdapterProfile(Context context, List<Profile> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.filterd = this.list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filterd.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filterd.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        }
        /*
         Profile myProfile = filterd.get(position);

         TextView textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);

         //TextView textChat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChat);
         //textChat.setText(myProfile.getPhone().toString());
         textName.setText(myProfile.getName().toString());
         }
         */
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        ProfileFilter filter = new ProfileFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    /** Class filter untuk melakukan filter (pencarian) */
    private class ProfileFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Profile> filteredData = new ArrayList<Profile>(); 
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            for(Profile myProfile: list){
                if(myProfile.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString) || myProfile.getIdCard().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                    filteredData.add(myProfile);
                }
            }
            result.count = filteredData.size();
            result.values =  filteredData;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filterd =  (List<Profile>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

private List<Profile> grantUp(){
    ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( "alex", "brian", "charles") );

    List<Profile> list = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    Profile myProfile = null;
    int iNum = 0;
    for(String name : namesList)
    {
        iNum++;
        myProfile = new Profile();
        myProfile.setId(iNum);
        myProfile.setName(name);
        list.add(myProfile);
    }
    return list;
}

public void publishContact(View v) {
    List<Profile> list = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    list = grantUp();
    int i = list.size();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapterProfile(getApplicationContext(), list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPhotoProfile);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```